# What is the purpose of the snap Gnome-3-34-1804 in Kubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: kubuntu, snap, sensors

I installed **gnome-3-34-1804** using the command `sudo snap install gnome-3-34-1804` (the base libraries and desktop integration components and shares it through the content interface) in Kubuntu 20.04.1, but I don't know what this installation in Kubuntu is for. What does this software do for me in Kubuntu?

Comment: "The gnome-3-34 snapcraft extension is a code addition to snapcraft itself that abstracts away some commonly used snapcraft.yaml lines while also tailoring the build environment of GNOME application snaps. While this extension contains GNOME in the name and is tailored to GNOME apps, it is worth noting that the extension provides many of the components needed for desktop applications in general, making it useful for a broader set of applications than just GNOME." -- for more details, please read https://readyspace.com.sg/gnome-3-34-snapcraft-extension/